# Confusing checkbox issue

Tags: java, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes and 2 counters... `counter1` counts how many of the checkboxes are checked with the following code

```
if (isChecked) {
    counter++;
} else {
    counter--;
}
```

This works like a charm but now i want that `counter2` keeps track of the checked checkboxes that belong to the "green" group... for example checkbox 1, 2, 4 and 7 belong to the " green" group and checkbox 3, 5, 6, 8 not.

```
if (chk1.isChecked() || chk2.isChecked() || chk4.isChecked() || chk7.isChecked()) {
    counter2++;
}
```

I tried to use another `if else` to see how much of the "green" group are checked 
But when I use

```
System.out.println(counter2);
```

then I always get the the value of `counter1`.
Why is this happening? Is it because `counter1` checks for all checked boxes and overrules `counter2`?

Comment: Where is code with 'counter2'?

Comment: @Dunk With this `if` clause, you will increment your `counter2` **once** if any of these checkboxes are checked, not for each of them... Put all checkboxes of one type in a list, iterate over it and increment you `counter2` if checkbox is checked.

Comment: There's not enough to go on here. Why don't you show all your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int counter2 = 0; // reset counter    
for (Checkbox chk : allCheckboxes)  
    {   
       if (chk.isChecked() && isGreen(chk)) {
           counter2++;
       }  
    }   
    //...
```

and utilily method

```
private boolean isGreen(Checkbox chk)  
{  
 // return true is checkbox is green  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated above in a comment, you check once if any of the boxes is checked. If the counter2 always shows the same value as counter1, that could be the result of a simple typo or something. Impossible to say without seeing your code. But a variable can not just *overrule* another variable.
Are you using `Swing`and `JCheckBox`? If so, you can add an `ItemListener` to it, if you don't have one already. Then you can dynamically update your counter to reflect the current state of your checkboxes. The code for the `itemStateChanged` method could look something like this:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) { 
        counter--;
    } else {
        counter++;
    } 
    // update label or something
}
```

You can use a different `ItemListener`for your *green group*, which additionally sets `counter2`. 
 This frees you from all the iterative checking.